# Is there any modern way to do games with ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, game-engine

I know it is possible to develop games with ActionScript. My question is:

> Is there any way to generate a game like "Unity" does, with Adobe tools, without ask the user to install 3rd party plugins (Flash Player, Adobe Air)?

I would like to do a game with ActionScript, for mobile platforms, without the inconvenience of installing third party plugins. Is it possible?

How are made games like `Clash Royale`?

Appreciate.

Comment: You can publish iOS and android apps with Adobe air. When have you ever had to instal 3rd party software to run an app on your phone? Yes, for desktop apps they would have to install Air, but not for a mobile app

Comment: As for clash royale, flash can support away3D and multiplayer so one could make a game like that in flash I suppose.

Comment: _"How are made games like `Clash Royale`?..."_ read stuff like this [**making-of article**](http://www.pocketgamer.biz/feature/45814/chart-rush-making-of-clash-of-clans/). Are you asking about server, graphic design, graphics programming, sounds or maybe AI programming? Be specific for a faster Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export your Adobe AIR projects as standalone executable files, for example:

- For Android you can export your app with the Captive Runtime, it will generate an APK ready to install. This APK won't require Adobe AIR installed on the user's device.
- For iOS, AIR always exports the IPA with Captive Runtime, you don't have to worry about this platform.
- For Windows, you can export an .exe file (only when you are using the AIR SDK for Windows).
- For OSX, you can export an .app file or a .dmg file (only when you are using the AIR SDK for OSX).

If you want to export for all 4 platforms I recommend to code and design on a Mac, so you can export the .app/.dmg, .apk and .ipa binaries, and use a VM or a cheap Windows computer for compiling your .exe file.